# Is there an iPhone SDK API that I can use to get the current wallpaper image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there an iPhone SDK API that I can use to get the current wallpaper image? I would like to use this image in a game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is currently no API that enables you to do this.

Answer (score 4):

There is no API to do this, but you may be able to load /User/Library/LockBackground.jpg using `+[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`

Note: this file won't exist if the user hasn't changed from the default "globe" wallpaper

Answer (score 1):

There is a private API, usual App Store rejection disclaimer applies

[UIImage defaultDesktopImage]

Comment: how can I call this, I tried  id imageClass = [UIImage class];
   
UIImage *bg = [imageClass performSelector:@selector(defaultDesktopImage) withObject:nil];
   but ap crashed